# Next.js Where to add Initial call to retrieve the user profile

Tags: next.js

I have a next.js app.
On init I need to call an action which retrieve the user and set it on the state.
This should happen only once and only in the app start (probably only server side).
Where is the right position to do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

inside app.js

```
    static async getInitialProps({ Component }) {
.
.
if(!process.browser)
{
... make your calls here
let results = data
}
```

append the result of the API call to the ...appProps

```
appProps.serverData = results
```

and return the ...appProps

you can either set the server data values into a context provider or set it inside apps state. The context will make the state values accessible in other pages and you can overcome props drilling.